# How to add class to an item in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

https://codepen.io/nuzze/pen/yLBqKMY
My problem is the next one: 
I have this list on my Vue data:

```
{
    name: 'Camp Nou',
    id: 'campNou'
},
{
    name: 'Abran cancha',
    id: 'abranCancha'
}
```

And I have a external function to adding class to both items:

```
var abranCanchabutton = $(".abranCancha-fav");
var campNoubutton = $(".campNou-fav");
window.onload = () => {
//abranCancha
if (localStorage.getItem('abranCancha')=='true') {
  abranCanchabutton.removeClass("favorite");
  abranCanchabutton.addClass("unfavorite");
  document.getElementById('abranCancha').classList.add('favorites');
  abranCanchabutton.attr("onclick", "quitabranCancha()");
}
else {
  abranCanchabutton.removeClass("unfavorite");
  abranCanchabutton.addClass("favorite");
  abranCanchabutton.attr("onclick", "favabranCancha()");
}
//campNou
if (localStorage.getItem('campNou')=='true') {
  campNoubutton.removeClass("favorite");
  campNoubutton.addClass("unfavorite");
  document.getElementById('campNou').classList.add('favorites');
  campNoubutton.attr("onclick", "quitcampNou()");
}
else {
  campNoubutton.removeClass("unfavorite");
  campNoubutton.addClass("favorite");
  campNoubutton.attr("onclick", "favcampNou()");
}
}
//functions
function favabranCancha() {
  document.getElementById('abranCancha').classList.add('favorites');
  localStorage.setItem('abranCancha', 'true');
  abranCanchabutton.removeClass("favorite");
  abranCanchabutton.addClass("unfavorite");
  abranCanchabutton.attr("onclick", "quitabranCancha()");
}
function quitabranCancha() {
  document.getElementById('abranCancha').classList.remove('favorites');
  localStorage.removeItem('abranCancha');
  abranCanchabutton.removeClass("unfavorite");
  abranCanchabutton.addClass("favorite");
  abranCanchabutton.attr("onclick", "favabranCancha()");
}
function favcampNou() {
  document.getElementById('campNou').classList.add('favorites');
  localStorage.setItem('campNou', 'true');
  campNoubutton.removeClass("favorite");
  campNoubutton.addClass("unfavorite");
  campNoubutton.attr("onclick", "quitcampNou()");
}
function quitcampNou() {
  document.getElementById('campNou').classList.remove('favorites');
  localStorage.removeItem('campNou');
  campNoubutton.removeClass("unfavorite");
  campNoubutton.addClass("favorite");
  campNoubutton.attr("onclick", "favcampNou()");
}
```

So, when you click the button "add to favorites", "unfavorite" class is added to the item selected, and then, if you click the button "remove from favorites", "unfavorite" class is removed and "favorite" class it's added. Well, I want to get the same thing but with Vue. I mean, I don't want to create functions for each item, I want a function that automatically adds the class to the selected item. Please I need heelp with this.

Thanks and sorry for my poor english :(

Comment: Please include your attempt at implementing this in Vue.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nuzze/pen/yLBqKMY

Comment: use onClick with event.target and add class, or use an array with map on each item in the list with style condition or class condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I forked your pen with the solution
```

https://codepen.io/christiancazu/pen/mdbjLVN

Comment: So nice!!! thankss, but the "favorites" class is not added to <li>. Can you update the pen? thank you, again<3

Comment: i didn't found any class called "favorites" on your css styles.

Comment: I mean, if you check my pen, when you click on the fav button, a "favorites" class is added to the <li>